# Wpf DataGrid (German) Date Sort

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, date, datagrid

I am looking for a (preferably XAML only) solution to Auto-Sort a WPF `DataGrid` by a column which displays date values in `dd.MM.yyyy` format. The `DataGrid`s `ItemSource` is a `DataTable`, which is read from a XML string.

The Code that I already have does not seem to work, however, if I set e.g. SortDirection="Ascending" on a column that displays ints, it does work. I left out everything of the Code that is not relevant for my question.

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataTable}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" SortDirection="Ascending"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Edit:

The `DataTable` is deserialized by the Method `DataTable.ReadFromXml()` from the following string:

```
<DataTable
    xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data\">
    <xs:schema id=\"NewDataSet\"
        xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
        xmlns=\"\"
        xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\">
        <xs:element name=\"NewDataSet\" msdata:IsDataSet=\"true\" msdata:MainDataTable=\"ResultTable\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\"true\">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs=\"0\" maxOccurs=\"unbounded\">
                    <xs:element name=\"ResultTable\">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name=\"Date\" type=\"xs:dateTime\" minOccurs=\"0\"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram
        xmlns:diffgr=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\"
        xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\">
        <DocumentElement
            xmlns=\"\">
            <ResultTable diffgr:id=\"ResultTable1\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\">
                <Date>2017-03-11T00:00:00+01:00</Date>
            </ResultTable>
            <ResultTable diffgr:id=\"ResultTable2\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\">
                <Date>2017-22-11T00:00:00+01:00</Date>
            </ResultTable>
            <ResultTable diffgr:id=\"ResultTable3\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\">
                <Date>2017-03-11T00:00:00+01:00</Date>
            </ResultTable>
        </DocumentElement>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

Edit #2:

Instead of trying to find a (apparently rather difficult) Xaml-Only solution, I am now sorting the DataTable directly in MySQL from where I fetch it. This proves as a more easy and fast-forward solution.

Comment: Does the user need to be able to sort columns by clicking on them or could you just sort in the code behind?

Comment: After more study I think this is probably because of the string format in the binding causing it to sort as the resulting string. Can you try using the format yyyy-MM-dd to see if that works.

Comment: Is `Date` a DateTime or a string? IIRC, a DateTime column is by default sorted by the underlying DateTime, not by the displayed data.

Comment: @apc Thanks for your answer :) the user should be able to sort too, and if he clicks on the Header the sorting appears to work as well..

Comment: @Kilazur Date is a DateTime in the DataTable

Comment: @apc It does not work either when I format it as you suggested, but nevertheless thanks for your tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of binding to the `DataView` you could bind to a `CollectionViewSource` that sorts the view by the `Date` property by default:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding MyDataTable}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Date" Direction="Ascending" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer. I tried it but sadly it does not work as well. Do you have any idea why it would not work? Also I am not binding to a DataView, but rather to a DataTable. I dont know if that makes a difference

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data that can be used to reproduce your issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Make sure that the Date property returns the value you expect.

Comment: this is the exact value (taken from the Debugger) that the particular column has: `11.03.2017 00:00:00`

Comment: btw, thanks for pointing out the Guidelines for posting a question :) in addittion to the date value, I have to say that I serialize the DataTable from XML, and the value there is `<Date>2017-03-11T00:00:00+01:00</Date>` . I then read the XML using `new DataTable.ReadXml()` which apperently turns the date `string` into the already culture specific `11.03.2017`

Comment: The type of the column in the DataTable should be DateTime for you to be able to sort the column values as dates and not alphabetical strings.

Comment: I just checked it, and the Column Type actually is DateTime .. I dont know what else to check, do you have any more ideas?

Comment: As mentioned, you should provide a reproducible sample of your issue if you want anyone to be able to help you any further.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the question now so that it becomes reproducable (I hope)

Comment: You should include your code that actually calls the ReadXml() method and set the MyDataTable property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SortMemberPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortmemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) on your column to define what property should be used for sorting.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I have not yet tried it since I solved that problem by sorting the data just when I get it (in MySQL). But I appreciate your answer and will try it soon